# How do I calculate dice with addition and subtraction based on dice rolls?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to figure out how to calculate results on a group of dice where some results are positive and others are negative.

Example: I roll a group of dice that are fair and six-sided. Each roll of $5$ or $6$ is a $+1$. Each roll of $1$ is a $-1$. I need to know how to calculate the probability for different size groups of dice depending on the overall result being positive, zero, or negative.

---

**Edit:**

To clarify:
I roll $x$ dice with the possible results of $-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1$ for each die.

1. What is the chance that the sum would be negative ($5\%, 20\%$, whatever)?
2. What is the chance that the sum would be zero ($5\%, 20\%$, whatever)?
3. What is the chance that the sum would be positive ($5\%, 20\%$, whatever)?

I am trying to find a formula that will let me input various numbers of dice and get the percentage chances for negative, zero, and positive. I am not sure what a multinomial distribution is and was thinking of just setting my computer for a brute force attack and count each possibility, but would rather not.

Further clarification:
Someone did a sample roll of *1000d6* and came up with a distribution result. that is nice but doesn't answer my question.
I did *4d6* by brute force since that is only 1296 possible combinations and came up with specific results.
There is a *19.68%* chance of getting a negative result.
There is a *24.77%* chance of getting a zero result.
There is a *55.56%* chance of getting a positive result.
I truncated the results, figuring that was enough significant decimal places.
What I am trying to find is what is the formula to calculate these results.

Comment: So you effectively have fair, six-sided dice with values $\{-1,0,0,0,1,1\}$?

Comment: So, with one die the probability of {-1,0,1} will be equal to {1/6,3/6,2/6}. With two dice (6*6=36 outcomes) the negative can be obtained as (-1,0) or (0,-1) or (-1,-1), thus with probability (1/6)*(3/6)+(3/6)*(1/6)+(1/6)*(1/6)=7/36. A zero can be obtained as (0,0), (-1,1), (1,-1) thus (3/6)(3/6)+ (1/6)(2/6)+(2/6)(1/6)=13/36. A positive as (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) thus (3/6)(2/6)+(2/6)(3/6)+(2/6)(2/6)=4/9. Since (7/36)+(13/36)+(4/9)=1 this seems OK. For 3 or more dice you have to consider all the various possibilities.

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. Can you you explain exactly what 'the probability' is that you seek? It might help if you could show us a bit of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**

The Comment by @GiovanniResta gives results for getting negative,
zero, or positive sums when two dice are rolled. I'm checking
these results by simulating a million rolls of a pair of dice in R.
I use dice as proposed by @Logophobic.

```
 die = c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
 B = 10^6;  n = 2
 faces = sample(die, B*n, repl=T)
 MAT = matrix(faces, nrow=B) # B x n matrix, each row an n die experiment
 x = rowSums(MAT);  table(x)/m  # totals on n dice
 ## x
 ##       -2       -1        0        1        2 
 ## 0.027880 0.166367 0.361880 0.332582 0.111291 

 mean(x < 0);  mean(x==0);  mean(x > 0)  # whether totals are neg, zero, or pos
 ## 0.194247  # compare:  7/36 =  0.1944444; (0.027880 + 0.166367 = 0.194247)
 ## 0.36188   # compare: 13/36 =  0.3611111
 ## 0.443873  # compare:  4/9  =  0.4444444
```

This is one possible interpretation of your question, and
simulation results agree with the proposed exact ones to 2 or 3 places,
as they should with a million rolls.
I do not see how this method can be easily generalized to
other values of $n$.

However, it occurs to me that
you might want an answer using the $multinomial\,$ $distribution.$ 
It is not clear to me exactly what you $are$
asking. What do you mean by "the probability" in your Question. Please state your question more explicitly.

**Addendum:** Based on your clarification, here are simulation results for $n = 3$ and $n = 4$.  Same code as for $n = 2$, just change the number.

```
 n = 3
 x
       -3       -2       -1        0        1        2        3 
 0.004721 0.041662 0.152111 0.291366 0.305879 0.167397 0.036864 
 mean(x < 0);  mean(x==0);  mean(x > 1)
## 0.198494
## 0.291366
## 0.204261

n = 4
x
      -4       -3       -2       -1        0        1        2 
0.000778 0.009277 0.048022 0.138436 0.247043 0.278741 0.191518 
        3        4 
 0.073865 0.012320 

 mean(x < 0);  mean(x==0);  mean(x > 1)
 ## 0.196513
 ## 0.247043
 ## 0.277703
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous result in probability which says that the sum of two probability distributions is the convolution of them.

So you can either solve this by iterated convolution or if you want to do it more fancy and advanced with Fourier Transforms.

However you should be able to calculate the expected value, right? On average we should add $(-1+0+0+0+1+1) \cdot 1/6 = 1/6$ each dice throw. This gives the expected sum of 10000 throws should be $10000/6$ = $1666.6\cdots$

A short Matlab or Octave script doing iterated convolutions of the probability distribution $p = [1/6,3/6,2/6]$ can give the below plot:

[image]

As we can see on this histoyram we have our peak around 1660 somewhere.

Actually it needs to be fairly symmetric since these throws have all the same distribution and you have probably heard of [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which says that the sum of a large number of equidistributable random variables will be normal.

Answer (score 0):

### Exact method number 1

As you showed, if $n$ is not too large it is possible to calculate
the probabilities by counting up all the outcomes in the $6^n$ possible
rolls of the dice.

### Exact method number 2

It is possible to count a little more "efficiently" if we
consider only three possible outcomes for each die, $-1$, $0$, or $1$,
weighted appropriately: weight $1$ for $-1$, weight $3$ for $0$, and weight $2$ for $1$. Then can look at just $3^n$ outcomes, as long as
(for example) we count $(-1,-1,1,1)$ four times as much as $(-1,-1,-1,-1)$.
If we make the weights $\frac16$, $\frac12$, and $\frac13$, the "weight" of
each outcome will be its probability.

### Exact method number 3

We can reduce the number of terms to examine even more if we
consider all possible permutations of a given roll as one event,
for example we count $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(1,0,0)$ all together.
The probability of $a$ dice worth $-1$, $b$ dice worth $0$,
and $c$ dice worth $1$ is
$$
\frac{n!}{a!b!c!} 
\left(\frac16\right)^a \left(\frac12\right)^b \left(\frac13\right)^c
$$

You can also decide to count just the negative and zero sums.
For example, for $n=8$, count the outcomes $(a,b,c) = (8,0,0), (7,1,0), \ldots, (1,7,0), (7,0,1), \ldots, (4,1,3)$ as "negative" outcomes and count
$(a,b,c) = (4,0,4),(3,2,3),(2,4,2),(1,6,1),(0,8,0)$ as "zero" outcomes.
The probability the sum is negative (or zero) is the sum of all the
probabilities of "negative" (or "zero") events; to find
the probability that the sum is positive, subtract the other
two probabilities from $1$.

This may be about as close to an "exact formula" as you can get:
setting $a = c + 1 + k$ in the formula above for a negative sum,
$a = c$ for a zero sum,
\begin{align}
P(\text{sum} < 0) 
&= \sum_{\substack{b,c,k\geq0\\ b+2c+k=n-1}}
   \frac{n!}{(c+k+1)!b!c!} \left(\frac16\right)^{c+k+1}
                 \left(\frac12\right)^b \left(\frac13\right)^c \\
&= \frac{n!}{6} \sum_{\substack{b,c,k\geq0\\ b+2c+k=n-1}}
   \frac{1}{(c+k+1)!b!c!} 
   \left(\frac12\right)^{b+c+k} \left(\frac13\right)^{2c+k}, \\
&= \frac{n!}{6} \sum_{a=1}^n 
   \sum_{c=0}^{\min\{a-1, n-a\}}
   \frac{1}{a!c!(n-a-c)!} 
   \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1-c} \left(\frac13\right)^{a+c-1},
\\
P(\text{sum} = 0) 
&= \sum_{\substack{a,b\geq0\\ 2a+b=n}}
   \frac{n!}{a! b! a!} 
   \left(\frac16\right)^a \left(\frac12\right)^b \left(\frac13\right)^a \\
&= n! \sum_{a = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
   \frac{1}{(a!)^2 (n-2a)!} 
   \left(\frac1{18}\right)^a \left(\frac12\right)^{n-2a}, \\
P(\text{sum} > 0) &= 1 - P(\text{sum} = 0) - P(\text{sum} < 0).
\end{align}

### "Fast" approximate method

For large enough values of $n$, you can approximate the
distribution by finding a normal distribution with the same mean and
variance and taking a histogram of the normal distribution around each
integer value.
That is, if $Y$ is the normal distribution constructed in this way,
for any integer $m$
$$P(\text{sum} = m) \approx P\left(m - \frac12 < Y < m + \frac12 \right).$$

The variable $X_i$ with $P(X_i = -1) = \frac16$, $P(X_i = 0) = \frac12$,
and $P(X_i = 1) = \frac13$ has mean
$$
E(X_i) = -1\cdot\frac16 + 1\cdot\frac13 = \frac16
$$
and variance
$$
E(X_i^2) - (E(X_i))^2 
= \left(1\cdot\frac16 + 1\cdot\frac13\right) - \left(\frac16\right)^2
= \frac{17}{36}.
$$

Expectation and variance of random variables are additive, so
the sum of $n$ dice is a random variable with mean $\frac16 n$
and variance $\frac{17}{36} n$.

So let $Y$ be a normal variable with distribution 
$\mathcal N\left(\frac16 n, \frac{17}{36} n\right)$;
then $Z = \frac6{\sqrt{17n}}\left(Y - \frac16 n\right)$
is a standard normal random variable ($Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$) and
\begin{align}
P(\text{sum} < 0) &\approx P\left(Y < -\tfrac12\right)
 = P\left(Z < \frac{-3-n}{\sqrt{17n}}\right),\\
P(\text{sum} = 0) &\approx P\left(-\tfrac12 < Y < \tfrac12\right)
 = P\left(\frac{-3-n}{\sqrt{17n}} < Z < \frac{3-n}{\sqrt{17n}}\right),\\
P(\text{sum} > 0) &\approx P\left(Y > \tfrac12\right)
 = P\left(Z > \frac{3-n}{\sqrt{17n}}\right).
\end{align}

There is no "closed-form" formula for these probabilities of a normal
distribution, but you can look up the probabilities (using the variable $Z$)
in a table of the cumulative standard normal distribution
(sometimes called a table of $Z$-values) in just about any decent book on
probability or statistics,
and there are math libraries in many programming environments with which
you can compute those probabilities.